# LINQ with two lists predicate?

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a code like this:

```
string[] teamNames = teams.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
List<int> wins = new List<int>();
foreach(var _team in teamNames)
{
    wins.Add(matches.Count(x => 
        ((x.Team1 == _team && x.Maps.Count(map => map.Score1 > map.Score2) > x.Maps.Count(map => map.Score2 > map.Score1)) || 
        (x.Team2 == _team && x.Maps.Count(map => map.Score2 > map.Score1) > x.Maps.Count(map => map.Score1 > map.Score2))
        )));
}
```

I was wondering if you could somehow count the wins for each team without the foreach first which just yields team name after team name. Any ideas for that/

Comment: we need to see your structure - perhaps a `GroupBy` will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do it by replacing the `foreach` with a `Select`:

```
var wins = teamNames
    .Select(_team =>
        matches.Count(x => 
        ((x.Team1 == _team && x.Maps.Count(map => map.Score1 > map.Score2) > x.Maps.Count(map => map.Score2 > map.Score1)) || 
        (x.Team2 == _team && x.Maps.Count(map => map.Score2 > map.Score1) > x.Maps.Count(map => map.Score1 > map.Score2))
        ))
    )
.ToArray();
```

Comment: `teams.Select(t => matches.Count(m => m.Team1 == t.Name ...)` would be even better

Comment: @BrianKintz My first expression was a mistake, it should have been a straight `Select` with no `Sum`, because OP's query adds only one item per team name.

Comment: I noticed that too and edited my comment...see above

Comment: He would be better off using a GroupBy on matches and doing a left join on teams.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Yes, he would. However, the order of numbers would not necessarily match that of the names in `teamNames`, unless the same ordering is requested on both results. Since `wins` is an array connected to `teamNames` only through an index, this could present a hard-to-find problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Ah yes, I was making the assumption that returning a list/array of {teamname, wins} would be acceptable.  Not a big fan of multiple arrays with data associated by similar indexes over a single array/list of an object with all associated data.

Comment: Assuming `x.Maps` is an `ICollection`, it would also be worthwhile to replace the `x.Maps.Count(...) > x.Maps.Count(...)` with `x.Maps.Count(...) > x.Maps.Count/2`

Comment: @BrianKintz That wouldn't work if you have any ties. if `x.Maps.Count(map => map.Score2 > map.Score1)==1` and `x.Maps.Count(map => map.Score2 < map.Score1)==1` and `x.Maps.Count(map => map.Score2 == map.Score1)==1` for example.

Comment: @RobertMcKee That's a good point...I had tennis in my head (where AFAIK ties aren't possible).

Comment: @RobertMcKee His code wouldn't record your example as a win either, but mine would have a problem if `Count(t1 > t2) == 1`, `Count(t2 > t1) == 0` and `Count(t1 == t2) == 4`, which should be a win for t1 but isn't because t1 <= 2

Answer (score 0):

You can also use groupby directly on the matches without creating the teamNames.